# How to update target table from sub query in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have written below query to update sequence of order after deletion of any one of intermediate records in the table in MYSQL.

**Before Deletion:**

```
NoteId  --------   NoteOrder
   1       |          1
   2       |          3
   3       |          2
```

After deleting NoteId 2, I have to update NoteId 3 note order from 3 to 2.

```
NoteId  --------   NoteOrder
   1        |         1
   3        |         2
```

**Query:**

```
UPDATE note
   SET NOTEORDER = NOTEORDER -1
   WHERE NOTEORDER
   IN (Select NOTEORDER From note Where NOTEORDER >
               (Select NOTEORDER From note Where NOTEID = 2))
```

I am getting below error while executing above query. How to resolve the issue?

**Error Message:**

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'note' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: are you really going to use such a complex query for this requirement when there is a solution without any joins or IN operators?

Comment: @forpas, I have updated my question. What will happen with below update statement, which you have provided if I delete NoteId 3? UPDATE note SET NoteOrder = NoteOrder - 1 WHERE NoteId > 3; NoteId 2 order will not change from 3 to 2.

Comment: You did not just update the question. You changed the requirement. Your original requirement presented the column NoteOrder in order and you asked how to update the values after a deletion. In your new requirement there is no order in NoteOrder. So this is not about fixing the order after a deletion. It is just fixing the order. Since this is a new requirement you should ask a new question and not invalidate the answers that you really got.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Could you please help me to resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete more than one row in one steo, and still want the numbers to keep sequential, you can use this

The Join SELECT shows you also how to add ad teh same table in an UPDATE clause without getting your error

> ```
> CREATE TABLE note (
>   `NoteId` INT,
>   `NoteOrder` INt
> );
>
> INSERT INTO note
>   (`NoteId`, `NoteOrder`)
> VALUES
>   ('1',       '1'),
>   ('3','3');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM note
> ```
>
> ```
> NoteId | NoteOrder
> -----: | --------:
>      1 |         1
>      3 |         3
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE note n1 INNER JOIN (SELECT NoteId,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NoteId) rn FROM note) n2 USING(NoteId)
>    SET n1.NOTEORDER = n2.rn
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM note
> ```
>
> ```
> NoteId | NoteOrder
> -----: | --------:
>      1 |         1
>      3 |         2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6bffc038910977dfd33b37a651e5d35c)*

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are after something like this:

```
UPDATE note
SET NoteOrder = NoteOrder - 1
WHERE NoteOrder IN (
  SELECT NoteOrder FROM (
    SELECT NoteOrder 
    FROM note 
    WHERE NoteId > 2
  ) n  
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmqpx6e8uE6NMyxKbM44Ke/1).

Or:

```
UPDATE note
SET NoteOrder = NoteOrder - 1
WHERE NoteOrder >= (
  SELECT NoteOrder
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(NoteOrder) NoteOrder 
    FROM note
    WHERE NoteId > 2
  ) n  
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmqpx6e8uE6NMyxKbM44Ke/3).

But isn't this:

```
UPDATE note 
SET NoteOrder = NoteOrder - 1
WHERE NoteId > 2;
```

simpler?

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmqpx6e8uE6NMyxKbM44Ke/4).

Results:

```
| NoteId | NoteOrder |
| ------ | --------- |
| 1      | 1         |
| 3      | 2         |
```